# python: how to check using PyQT5 thread API if a thread still runs

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I just started learning `PyQT`, I'm able to create thread, start it, but didn't figure out yet how to check from GUI thread (the main thread) if the other thread is still running.

What is the right `QThread` method/API to do this?

Comment: Do you mean except for [`isRunning()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isRunning)  and [`isFinished()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isFinished)?